# Why does user_load($id) NOT return FALSE when an invalid id is passed in?

Tags: 7, users

I'm making a module that lets users manage database records for various organizations.  I'm using Drupal 7 and an very new at it.  I'm logged in as the admin user. I have a menu item 'cb' that checks args and returns content generated by various functions, here it is in the menu:

```
function org_menu() {
  $items['org'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Orgs',
    'page callback' => 'org_show_orgs',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['org/create_org'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create New Org',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('org_create_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['org/search_orgs'] = array(
    'title' => 'Find Orgs',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('org_search'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['org/cb'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'custom_callback',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

And this is the cb function that determines what I am trying to do, and calls the appropriate content function:

```
function custom_callback () {
  if ( arg(2)=="edit" )
    return org_edit_org();
  if ( arg(2)=="view" ) {
    return org_show_orgs();
  }
  return "<H3>Invalid callback function: '".arg(2)."'";
}
```

and the actual org_get_orgs function:

```
function org_show_orgs() {
  global $user;
  $acctid=arg(3);
  if ( !$acctid && $user->uid==0 )
    return array('my_content' => '<H3>My Orgs</H3>Please log in to view your orgs.'.
                    '<BR><H3>Find Orgs</H3>', drupal_get_form('org_search'));

  if ( $acctid ) {
    //return "case1 arg0=".arg(0)."<BR>arg1=".arg(1)."<BR>arg2=".arg(2)."<BR>arg3="
    //              .arg(3)."<BR>arg4=".arg(5)."<BR>acctid=$acctid<BR><BR>";
    $account=user_load($acctid);
    //return "case2 arg0=".arg(0)."<BR>arg1=".arg(1)."<BR>arg2=".arg(2)."<BR>arg3="
    //              .arg(3)."<BR>arg4=".arg(5)."<BR>acctid=$acctid<BR><BR>";
    if ( $account===FALSE )
      return "<H3>Invalid acctid "+$acctid+"</H3>";
    else
      return "<H3>account was not FALSE</H3>";
  }
}
```

cb() gets called correctly and the org_show_orgs() function gets called as expected.  arg(3) is the user id, so I can allow a user to view another user's orgs.

I hit the url 
http://example.com/?q=org/cb/view/1 
and it works - I see admin's orgs.  If I pick a userid for another user, it works - I see their orgs as well.  The problem is when I tinker with the url and pass in an id of a user that doesnt exist - then I get all kinds of weirdness.  For example, if I hit

http://example.com/?q=org/cb/view/4

If I uncomment that case2 line, I clearly see all my variables are correct:

```
case2 arg0=org
arg1=cb
arg2=view
arg3=4
arg4=
acctid=4
```

but if I try to test if $account===FALSE, I get the maintenance page.  If I change the id to 3, I get an 'access denied' page.  If I change the id to 2, I see a 'page not found' page.  If I try return print_r($account,TRUE); I get the menus and a completely blank content cell.  No error, which I'd get it it was a non-array object.  If I try get_class($account) after I retrieve it, I get the menus but no css, and everything is just listed down the left side, no regions, themes, nothing.

Besides the $account issue, is there a better way to be doing this than that callback menu, or is that the drupal way?

Comment: `user_load()` is documented to return `FALSE` if it fails. Can you verify that it doesn't work outside of your complex workflow? If you simply run `$account = user_load(4);` in a standard Drupal page callback does it return `FALSE`?

Answer (score 1):

The account test probably is working, but this is wrong:

```
return "<H3>Invalid acctid "+$acctid+"</H3>";
```

If the $acctid is an integer, it's evaluating that and returning an integer.  The proper php concatenation operator is '.' (without the quotes), change your return statement to

```
return "<H3>Invalid acctid ".$acctid."</H3>";
```

It'll evaluate to the string you're presumably expecting.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the value returned by user_load() is an array. If the $id is not valid, it will return an empty array.

Try changing your test to `if (empty($account))`.

Comment: It returns `FALSE` for me when I run it with an invalid user ID, and a `stdClass` object on success (Drupal 7). I've never seen it return an array before, is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @Clive - If you trace the function through the Drupal API, the actual return value comes from [entity_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7).

Comment: `user_load()` takes the return value from `user_load_multiple()` (which uses `entity_load()`). _That_ return val is an array, but `user_load()` runs `reset()` on it. Running `reset()` on an empty array results in `FALSE`.

Comment: @Clive - Good catch. I missed it. However, empty() is a more generic method of testing for a FALSE value, and drupalnewbie for some reason is tryng to compare handles, not values. At least the comparison should be '==' and not '==='.

Answer (score -1):

These tests will not work in recent PHP, because account is an object array. Use the following condition: `if (count($account) > 0)`